# Extract element from nested list of rolling_origin R

Tags: r

I want to extract, .metrics (RMSE) from a Rolling origin forecast resampling
(tibble: 52 x 5) by "id" columns which consist of slices.

The replicating codes are given below. Here is my attempt.

```
metric <- resamples_fitted$.resample_results
metric
```

[image]

```
all <- metric[[1]][[".metrics"]]
res <- unlist(all)
estimate <- res[ grepl(".estimate", names(res))]
```

I want to get the  ".estimate" by "slices" in the data frame. For each slice, there will be one RMSE. These are full codes

```
library(tidymodels)
library(modeltime)
library(modeltime.resample)
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)
library(resample)

resample_spec <- rolling_origin(
  data        = m750,
  initial    = 200,
  assess     = 3,
  cumulative = TRUE,
  skip       = 1,
  overlap    = 0 )



resamples_fitted <- m750_models %>%
  modeltime_fit_resamples(
    resamples = resample_spec,
    control   = control_resamples(verbose = FALSE)
  )

resamples_fitted

metric <- resamples_fitted$.resample_results
metric
all <- metric[[1]][[".metrics"]]

res <- unlist(all)
estimate <- res[ grepl(".estimate", names(res))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time, I found a solution, which may not be very elegant though, it solves the problem.

```
metric <- resamples_fitted$.resample_results
metric
all <- metric[[1]][[ ".metrics"]]

res <- unlist(all)
estimate <- res[ grepl(".estimate", names(res))]
typeof(estimate)

dat <- as.data.frame(sapply(estimate, as.numeric)) 

data <- dat[complete.cases(dat), ]

all_id <- data.frame(metric[[1]]$id)
al <- cbind(all_id,data)
```